# Introductory text for Group Rings

Tags: reference-request, group-rings

Is there any other text books on Group rings except *The algebraic structures of Group Rings by D.Passman*. This book is really good but it will help if I know about other books on the topic too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, here there are some suggestions:

- [*An Introduction to Group Rings*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-1-4020-0238-0) by César Polcino Milies, and Sudarshan Sehgal.
- *Topics in group rings* by Sudarshan K. Sehgal (Monographs and Textbooks in
  Pure and Applied Mathematics, vol. 50, Marcel Dekker, New York and Basel, 1978)

Comment: Thanks. After my own search, I also found these two, and also Units in group rings by Sehgal... These are really good books. Thanks alot.

Comment: You're welcome!