# Some results about Group Rings/Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

I'm trying to build up my intuition on group algebras, $k[G]$ where $k$ is a field. Here are some things I'd like to know about:

> 1. If $H \leq G$ then is $k[H]$ a subalgebra of $k[G]$?
> 2. If $G_1, G_2$ are groups, what can we say about $k[G_1 \oplus G_2]$?

I don't know if 1 is true but it seems reasonable.

EDIT: My idea for this:  Use the inclusion of H into G to give an inclusion of $k[H]$ into $k[G]$, which commutes with the structure map of the $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

**Also** if anyone can recommend a good text discussing group rings in detail, I would be very interested.

EDIT 2: What happens if the $k$ is replaced by a general ring?

Comment: 1. Yes, if you appropriately identify elements of $k\left[H\right]$ with elements of $k\left[G\right]$. A cleaner statement would be "Any group homomorphism $H \to G$ induces a $k$-algebra homomorphism $k\left[H\right]\to k\left[G\right]$, and if the former is injective, then so is the latter.".

Comment: 2. What would your guess be? (What is an operation on $k$-algebras similar to the direct sum operation on groups?)

Comment: Group algebras play a great role in Peter Webb's book on representation theory ( http://www.math.umn.edu/~webb/RepBook/ ), although I'm not sure in how much detail he goes about their basic properties.

Comment: I think the only place you'll find a discussion of group algebras is places they're used for other things. For instance, you could look at the book Representations and Characters of Groups by James & Liebeck, where they're used because they're relevant to group representations

Comment: Well an initial guess would be $k[G_1 \oplus G_2] \cong k[G_1] \times k[G_2]$

Comment: What problem did you encounter when trying to use your idea for 1? And with your initial guess about the direct sum?

Comment: @Mariano I was not very confident with the material, so was checking my thought process was along the right lines

Comment: Nothing develops confidence as actually doing things! It is infinitely more useful to ask this sort of question by writing the details of what you did.

Comment: @AlexMathers That's rather pessimistic about group algebras as a discipline! There are several great books I would highly recommend: Passman's *The algebraic structure of group rings*, and Milies and Sehgal's *An introduction to group rings*, Gilmer's *Commutative semigroup rings*.

Comment: @rschwieb shows how little I know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, $K[H]$ is embedded naturally in $K[G]$ because $K[H]=\{a\in K[G]\mid supp(a)\subseteq H\}$. Here $supp(a)$ is the support of $a$.
2. Consider the tensor product: Lemma $3.4$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=2xrSHX-rpGMC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=group+algebra+K%5BG+x+H%5D+is+isomorphic+to+tensor+product+of+K%5BG%5D+and+K%5BH%5D&source=bl&ots=0Mrwio077p&sig=bYQJMKEyQAIKChRkUUgeiIc0OH8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGwZDe9brQAhVFB8AKHXQuD3IQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=group%20algebra%20K%5BG%20x%20H%5D%20is%20isomorphic%20to%20tensor%20product%20of%20K%5BG%5D%20and%20K%5BH%5D&f=false).
3. References on text books: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095479/introductory-text-for-group-rings).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learned about the tensor product yet, so I've got that to look forward to. I guess if you replace $k$ with any ring, all the results still hold (but with ring isomorphisms instead of algebra ones)?